# Any side effect for chocolatey if software updates by itself and one tries to update through choco again?

Tags: package-managers, chocolatey

Some programs installed by Chocolatey have the feature to self-update. Examples are VS code and PyCharm. Will there be any side effects if one uses choco to upgrade the software after the software has done the self-update?

I am using Windows 10, python 3.8, anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "side effects" you mean try to download when they shouldn't, or download and revert to outdated files that they shouldn't, the answer is no. They don't just retrieve the packages, they manage them.

handling dependencies during installs and upgrades is the main purpose for package mgrs. to exist. They manage stuff like that so developers do not need to. Otherwise, building any type of project with current methods and standards would be extremely challenging so you don't have to.

Chocolatey, like most package mgrs., runs a 2 step process as a result of the upgrade command. First it checks for newer versions, If there are none, it does nothing. The convention for nearly all automatic upgrade processes  is the same. Because of this, either one only retrieves when it needs to.

Companies like IntelliJ and Microsoft usually have relatively robust Deployment schemes, regardless of the method. If a package manager was going to break (or breaking) their automatic update, they would either fix the compatability issue or choose to forgoo the install method. So long as you verify your sources before downloading anything from anywhere, you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

#### Side Effects

Side effects should not be present, as it depends on whether the application also successfully overwrites the files, **which should be the case**.

If [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) executes the self-update and the [Chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org/) updates the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) application at the same time, errors may occur and the files may not be overwritten successfully.

---

#### 1. Solution — Deactivate Self-Update

You can manually disable the self-update option integrated in the application.

If the application does not allow you to disable the self-update option, try disabling the update service via the Services application.

---

#### 2. Solution - Deactivate the Update Service via Services

The **Services** application allows you to make configurations of the services developed by the respective application.

> **It is strongly recommended that you create a restore point before making any changes to services.**
>
> **If you make a mistake that cripples your computer, you can use the restore point to perform a system restore and undo the changes.**
>
> **If you have disabled the wrong service and lost access to the computer, try booting into safe mode to change the service back.**

Configure the update service via the **Services** application and set the status to **Disabled**.

---

- **Example:** Deactivating the Brave Update Service

[image: Example: Deactivating the Brave Update Service]